# Different behavior with "if" and the ternary operator

Tags: swift

I'm able to compile this:

```
if (line == selectedLine) {

}
```

where `line` is of type `Line`, whereas `selectedLine` is a nullable of the same type.

But this fails:

```
layer.strokeColor = (line == selectedLine ? UIColor.greenColor() : line.color.CGColor)
```

with error `Line is not convertible to MirrorDisposition`

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to set a layer stroke color to a `UIColor`. You should instead use `.CGColor` like you did for your second case.

Error messages are not always the most helpful in Swift.

Also, put the brackets around the condition only.

Comment: Yes, I wrote it as answer. I will accept yours anyway, in fairness.

Answer (score 1):

`UIColor.greenColor()` returns a `UIColor` instance.

Try using

`UIColor.greenColor().CGColor`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the error was that I needed to get the `CGColor` property from `UIColor.greenColor()`

Once more, the Swift compiler seems not reliable on its messages...